# How is a Cybertronian born?

Tags: transformers

How are Autobots born?

I understand how the “soul” of a Transformer is made (Primus gives them life) but how does the body of an Autobot unite with the soul?

I’m basically asking whether the body is pre-made or does it just magically spawn?

Comment: This could probably use some clarification regarding which Transformers continuity you want to know about. There are a LOT of different continuities now, between multiple cartoon series, multiple comics series, and the live action films - and the answer will differ somewhat for each. (For instance, Primus does not exist in the original cartoon series.)